# MYSQLQuery to get all chat message for particular user?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to get all the message for a particular user

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77q3j.png)

this is my table structure and I have one user id (in this case suppose my user id is 31 ) and want the MySQL query to get all chat for that specific user ( user id 31 )

Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, message FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 31
```

change the user_id to sender_user_id/receiver_user_id. According to what you're querying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OR` condition as follows:

```
select * 
  from `tbl_chat_details` 
 where sender_user_id = 31 or receiver_user_id = 31
```

Comment: thank you that works !! but I want a specific chat for 31 user id mean for chat between 31 and 37

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  SENDER_USER_ID AS USER_ID, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(MESSAGE) AS USER_MESSAGES 
FROM MESSAGE_TABLE 
GROUP BY SENDER_USER_ID;
```

Hope this helps! Happy learning :)

Comment: Thanks, but the user id could be sender or receiver , and i want specific chat